# What was the murderer's long-term plan?

Tags: luther

The murderer's plan near the end of *Luther: The Fallen Sun* was supposed to culminate in him debuting a website where would-be murderers could vicariously participate in his killing of random people from his Estonian bunker, a la [*Red Rose*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Rose_(TV_series)).

However, by all appearances, the livestream was public, since the police were able to access it, and from the glimpses that we see, Robey's real face and voice were apparently visible. Further, Robey had revealed his face while holding a knife to a bystander in the middle of a crowded London square with innumerable bystanders and cameras. Finally, whatever he had intended to do with respect to DCI Raine, it would presumably have ended with him having little leverage over the case: either because she had her daughter back, or because her daughter was dead, or because both were dead and the case was handed over to someone else. In short, Robey seemingly would have had little possibility of either concealing his identity or controlling the course of the investigation, and presumably knew this at that point.

As such, what were Robey's plans for after he revealed his "Red Bunker" stream? Did he have a plan to try to avoid capture? Did he simply  not care what happened next, thinking that it was enough to achieve his life's work?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable.  However it is worth considering if he didn't intend to be revealed at Piccadilly.  It's not clear how much of that event went to his plan.  Perhaps he intended to use his digital face mask on the live stream but since he had been identified that was pointless.  He may have assumed he could disappear using his extensive network of corrupted agents and presumed large fortune.   Also, the live stream is unlikely to be public since the audience were expected to pay.  This doesn't preclude the police from gaining access.

Answer (score 1):

The murders and the website launch plan were exposed to us, the viewers, but in no point during the movie we get an explanation of Robey's plans for after the livestream.

It appears that he wasn't planning to get captured: he seemed surprised / upset when he found out his wife wasn't prevented from speaking to the police, for example. All we know is that the streaming IP was not traceable, and that he had enough resources to keep digging dirt on whatever random person was needed to help him commit more crimes or cover up his tracks.